# Downloading FTP Files Skipping similar files

Tags: python, ftp, download

I am trying to download files from ftp server to my Python directory. I want to check if the files are present in one of the location in my computer. I want to skip the existing files and only copy the files which do not exist on the path to My Python Directory.

When I run the script it starts to download files. But, it copies the documents which exists as well as which doesn't exists. And then it disconnects in the midway. What corrections are to be made?
I know there are are similar examples, but please let me know why this doesn't work.
Here is my script.

```
 class Testing():
        def __init__(self):
            import ftplib
            f = ftplib.FTP('ftp_server_path','login_name','password')
            f.cwd('new_directory')
            f.cwd('new_directory')

            import os
            for ftp_file in f.nlst():

                for filename in os.listdir("path_where_files_exist"):

                    if not (ftp_file == filename):
                        print('Downloading file: %s', ftp_file)
                        f.retrbinary('RETR '+ ftp_file ,open(ftp_file,'wb').write,rest=0)
                        break;
            f.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the problem of overwriting the file.

```
for ftp_file in f.nlst():
    if ftp_file not in os.listdir("path_where_files_exist"):
        print('Downloading file: %s', ftp_file)
        f.retrbinary('RETR '+ ftp_file ,open(ftp_file,'wb').write,rest=0)
        f.quit()
```

using 2 loops and the condition was the problem.
Your code:

```
for ftp_file in f.nlst():
    for filename in os.listdir("path_where_files_exist"):
        if not (ftp_file == filename):
        #some code
```

for one `ftp_file` it will check with every `filename`. Everytime it found that `ftp_file` is not equal to `filename`, it was downloaded.

So even if the file exists, the condition will return True of every other `filename` in directory and the `ftp_file` will be downloaded the as many times as there are files in the directory.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. I missed it! Thanks.